# WSL2 : Why is windows gcloud in my WSL $path?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code

I've been working with WSL2 for some time and I'm very happy with it overall. I develop my applications with google cloud platform tools. However, I notice that every time I install a WSL distribution, I end up with the path of my Gcloud (windows) on my distribution. This causes a lot of problems.

I tried to deactivate path sharing, but it caused other problems, with VsCode as well as with Docker-in-WSL

Is it a configuration I did wrong or a known bug?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry wrong copy

Comment: It does sound like you already know why it happens and you have found the proper remedy for it but it does cause other issues. So you will probably need to pick either option and implement a workaround.